# hiding active nav-pill tab while showing not active nav-pill tab

Tags: jquery

I made a nav pill and I want to make the active tab hidden and not active tab to show.When I click on not active tab, then vise versa. I tried a code in jquery, but I need to click twice on tab.And also, at the time of loading the page, I need to trigger this click event

```
 <ul class="nav nav-pills" id='navpill'>
    <li class="active navGen"><a href="#sres" data-toggle="tab" style="padding:7px 7px 7px 7px;">Add Single Resource <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a></li
    <li class="navGen"><a href="#mres" data-toggle="tab" style="padding:7px 7px 7px 7px;">Add Bulk Resources <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a></li>
</ul>
<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="sres">
      Content1 here
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="mres">
      Content2 here
    </div>
</div>
```

### Jquery Code:

```
$(".navGen").on('click',function(){
    $("#navpill li.active").hide();
    $("#navpill li:not(.active)").show();
});
```

Comment: Are you intentionally mixing an active class with the inline show/hide of jQuery's show/hide methods? One alternative would be to add/remove/toggle the active class. You could also use `$(this).show()` combined with a `$('yourSelector').hide()` to hide all, and show the clicked pill

Comment: @GregMcMullen Actually, I need the code like when a tab is selected, then I need to hide that active tab. Rest of the tab has to be shown there. After that, when I click on another tab, I need to hide that tab and not active tabs has to be shown

Comment: You should be able to adjust the actual code as needed. The methodology is the same.

Comment: Can u check it with team viewer

Comment: Still trying to grasp what you even want to have happen. When you click on the nav pill item, do you want content to show/hide? Or the actual navigation item? If so Mohammed's code is what you want.

Comment: @GregMcMullen Mohammeds code I want, but output is not coming properly

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this .. With `$(this)` and `add/removeClass` it'll be easier to control that and by using `.index()` you can specify the index of tab you need to show *I assumed you'll need to show the tabs up to the `.navGen`*

```js
$(".navGen").on('click',function(){
  $(".navGen , .tab-pane").addClass('active');
  $(this).removeClass('active');
  $('.tab-pane:eq('+$(this).index()+')').removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.navGen , .tab-pane{
  display : none;
}
.navGen.active , .tab-pane.active{
  display : block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="nav nav-pills" id='navpill'>
    <li class="active navGen"><a href="#sres" data-toggle="tab" style="padding:7px 7px 7px 7px;">Add Single Resource <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="navGen"><a href="#mres" data-toggle="tab" style="padding:7px 7px 7px 7px;">Add Bulk Resources <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
    </li>

</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="sres">
        Content1 here
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="mres">
        Content2 here
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For me its not working..Can u check it with team viewer

Comment: @Sidharth **Not working** not enough to describe the problem .. if you've a live site let me check it

Comment: After adding your code, its working as normal nav-pill.I will give my team viewer ID and password.Can you check the problem with my code

Comment: @Sidharth I'm not working with a team viewer .. so please delete your id,password .. i'll upvote your question may someone else can help :: good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try with CSS as follows

```
$(".navGen").on('click',function(){
   $("#navpill li.active").removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

CSS:

```
#navpill li.active{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: No, still I need to hit twice on button

Comment: And also I need to trigger the click event on load